# Collapsing row-groups in Parquet efficiently

Tags: python, memory, compression, parquet

I have a large Parquet file with a number of small row groups.  I'd like to produce a new Parquet file with a single (bigger) row group, and I'm operating in Python.  I could do something like:

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
table = pq.read_table('many_tiny_row_groups.parquet')
pq.write_table(table, 'one_big_row_group.parquet')

# Lots of row groups...
print (pq.ParquetFile('many_tiny_row_groups.parquet').num_row_groups)
# Now, only 1 row group...
print (pq.ParquetFile('one_big_row_group.parquet').num_row_groups)
```

However, this requires that I read the entire Parquet file into memory at once.  I would like to avoid doing that.  Is there some sort of "streaming" approach in which the memory footprint can stay small?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pyarrow's `write_dataset` accepts an iterable of record batches, so you can avoid loading everything into a single in-memory table at once.

```py
import pyarrow.dataset as ds

input_dataset = ds.dataset("folder_of_tiny_rowgroup_parquets")
scanner = input_dataset.scanner()
ds.write_dataset(scanner, "folder_of_large_rowgroup_parquets", format="parquet", min_rows_per_group=20000)
```

This is not *quite* what you asked for because instead of rewriting file-by-file, the output will likely have fewer files than your input. That is, it may also compact across files.  It also limits the control you have of the name given to individual parquet file(s) that get written, although see the `basename_template` argument for some control there.

From: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/dataset.html#writing-large-amounts-of-data

Comment: Well, it's still the best answer I've gotten in 4 years :).  For interested readers, it appears that there is a "batch_size" kwarg in `scanner()` that can be used to control the batch size.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of `fastparquet` notes the possibility to iterate over datasets that are to big to fit in memory. For reading you can use:

```py
pf = ParquetFile('myfile.parquet')
for df in pf.iter_row_groups():
    print(df.shape)
    # process sub-data-frame df
```

For writing you can `append` to the file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't think fastparquet's `append=True` option will help me merge the row groups:  `append: bool (False)
If False, construct data-set from scratch; if True, add new row-group(s) to existing data-set. In the latter case, the data-set must exist, and the schema must match the input data.`  Examining the output confirms that you end up with multiple row groups.